# Missing the [goal]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

I recently asked a question concerning Prolog and the GOAL language. While entering tags I noticed that there was a [goal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/goal) tag and quickly added it to my question.

Now out of interest, I clicked it and found staggering variety of questions. Some dealing with setting actual goals in a program, others dealing with google-analytics-goal, some dealing with Maven, some dealing with Excel and even something about a dialect of Lisp called GOAL (Game Oriented Assembly Lisp).

My own question regarded something close to Prolog, meaning that we have in total 2 programming languages and 3 tools competing for this tag.

Now my (biased) proposal is to write a tag wiki for one of the two languages (whichever makes the most sense) and simply remove the tag for every other question. Currently there is not a single question where [goal] is the only tag, so this would leave no orphans. Removing it from all questions and then adding it back to either the oldest question (for GOAL the Lisp dialect) or to the newest question (for the Prolog version) would also be easy.

For some information about both languages

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GOAL_agent_programming_language

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_Oriented_Assembly_Lisp

Comment: *Missing the [goal]* should be the title of this thread.

Comment: I don't see any questions about the GOAL language, except for a [high-level one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4320166/how-to-stream-program-code) that could probably be closed (iirc the GOAL compiler is proprietary and very few people even know the language besides Andy Gavin at Naughty Dog).  The tag seems too generic to be of any value.  I say burninate it.

Comment: [Goal is a thing in Maven](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16205778/4639281)

Comment: There are 41 questions in [tag:goal], and only [6 questions that aren't about Maven](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoal%5D+-%5Bmaven*%5D+is%3Aq): 2 are about prolog and the GOAL language, 3 are about piwik, and 1 is about Lisp GOAL. I would suggest writing up a tag wiki about Maven Goals, then finding different tags for those 6 other questions.

Comment: @TinyGiant Would you support renaming the tag to [tag:maven-goal] to be more explicit?

Comment: I would support that @jpmc26

Comment: Of note is that it appears the common combination of google-analytics and goal has been retagged into goal-tracking.

Comment: That was me, most of them were tagged [tag:goal] and [tag:tracking] and there were already a great number of google-analytics questions tagged [tag:goal-tracking] so it made sense. There wasn't a whole lot in goal that were tagged that way, there was more in [tag:goals].

Comment: There were only two questions (both yours) which were tagged with both [prolog] and [goal], I've removed the tag. Feel free to propose a new tag just for those 2, if the need be, if not, all is well.

Comment: @BhargavRao as seen in the other question a number of other people haved asked prolog-goal questions in the past but the tag has already been cleared a few times. But I would propose a prolog-goal tag as a good way of distinguishing that particular language.

Comment: @Thijser Cool, I'll create the tag as soon as I'm back on my desk.